# Greens function of a uniformly charged sphere

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

The potential $\phi(\boldsymbol{x})$ satisfies

$\nabla^2\phi=f$

It may be shown that by defining an appropriate Green's function $g(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{\xi})$ that

$\phi(\boldsymbol{\xi})=\int_V g(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{\xi)} f(\boldsymbol{x})d^3\boldsymbol{x}$

Now if the Greens' function is $g(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{\xi})=\frac{-1}{4\pi|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\xi}|}$ and that

$f(\boldsymbol{x}) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1  & \mbox{if } \boldsymbol{|x|} < a \\
  0 & \mbox{if } a < \boldsymbol{|x|}
 \end{array}
\right.$

and denoting $ \boldsymbol{|\xi|}=R$ show that

$\phi(\boldsymbol{\xi}) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  -(\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{R^2}{6})  & \mbox{if } R < a \\
  -\frac{a^3}{3R} & \mbox{if } a < R
 \end{array}
\right.$

I get that

$ \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{a}\frac{-1}{4\pi(R^2+r^2-2Rrcos(\theta))^{1/2}}4\pi r^2 sin(\theta) dr d\theta$

with $\frac{d}{d\theta}|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\xi}|= \frac{4Rrsin(\theta)}{(R^2+r^2-2Rrcos(\theta))^{1/2}}$ so I get that

= $\frac{-1}{8R} \int_0^a r[R^2+r^2-2Rrcos(\theta)]^{1/2} \vert^\pi_0 dr$

= $\frac{-1}{8R} \int_0^a r[R+r-|R-r|] \vert^\pi_0 dr$

but this does not integrated to the required function.

Comment: There is a factor of 4 error in your computation of $\frac{d}{d\theta} |x-\xi|$.